# React data based Routing

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, trying to convert my asp.net site to React. i am facing some issues with routing.
I am maintaining my user's role based access (navigations) in database, post login i am retrieving the available navigations based on the logged in user.

I am able to configure my routs without any issues, but all my pages / components has lot of grids and the grid has links, which will drill down more in to that page to get details. in this case i am not able to configure my routes properly.

Ex: i have user component, which will list all the users, and i have edit icon, when i click i need to redirect to the corresponding user's profile screen, in this screen i have multiple links which will redirect to different page.

I dont want to add static routes for all my components, i need to dynamically generate routes based on the page where am i and redirect to the corresponding pages.

This is how my navigation looks like.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "navigation",
            "title": "Navigation",
            "type": "group",
            "icon": "icon-navigation",
            "children": [
                {
                    "url": "/Dashboard",
                    "title": "Dashboard",
                    "icon": "fa-solid fa-house",
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "Dashboard"
                },
                {
                    "url": "/Documents",
                    "title": "Documents",
                    "icon": "fa-solid fa-book",
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "Documents"
                },
                {
                    "url": "/Users",
                    "title": "Users",
                    "icon": "fas fa-users",
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "Users"
                },
                {
                    "url": "/Admin",
                    "title": "Admin",
                    "icon": "fas fa-th-large",
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "Admin"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my code to render the routes based on the above navigation.

```
const menu = this.state.routes && this.state.routes.map((route, index) => {
    return (route.component) ? (
        <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            name={route.name}
            render={props => (
                <route.component {...props} />
            )} />
    ) : (null);
});

<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
    <Switch>
        {menu}

        <Route path="*" component={Page404} />
    </Switch>
</Suspense>
```

And here is my user list data table

```
 const columns = [
            {
                name: "First Name",
                cell: (row) => row.fname,
                selector: (row) => row.fname,
                wrap: false,
                sortable: true,
            },
            {
                name: "Last Name",
                cell: (row) => row.lname,
                selector: (row) => row.lname,
                wrap: false,
                sortable: true,
            },
            {
                name: "Email",
                cell: (row) => row.email,
                selector: (row) => row.email,
                wrap: false,
                sortable: true,
            },
            {
                name: "Phone",
                cell: (row) => row.phone1,
                selector: (row) => row.phone1,
                wrap: false,
                sortable: true,
            }, {
                name: "Actions",
                cell: (row) => (<Link to={`/Users/manage/${row.Id}`} ><i className='fas fa-edit' /></Link>),
                wrap: false,
                sortable: false,
            },
        ];

 <DataTable
                    columns={columns}
                    data={this.props.users}
                    pagination
                    dense
                    fixedHeader
                    highlightOnHover
                    customStyles={customStyles}
                />
```

If you notice here, i have Action column which has a link, but for this link i don't have a relative route. i know we can add dynamic route with :id param, Since i am driving everything dynamically at run time, i dont want to add static routes for all of my components which has drill down links.

Comment: did you check this https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route?

Comment: We can't help address issues in code we can't see so please do [edit] your post to clarify what the specific issue or problem is and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with. If there are errors, include the complete error message and any accompanying stacktraces. Take the [tour] the see [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips for using the site and improving the quality of your post.